# regarding plots in visual dsp ++ 5.0

Tags: dsp-core

For my source code witten in c ,in visual dsp++ 5.0 for a forward error correcting code on adsp 21062 sharc family platform. i want to plot a graph between different data sets. when i tried to use the plot window, it is showing the data sets which are in assembly.so how to plot a graph between the input and output in the tool?please help me out.

phani tej

Comment: Do you mean you have signal x and signal y, and want to plot x-y? You can only do that in VDSP if you actually calculate z=x-y in your code and then plot z.

Answer (score 1):

export the data from memory and process it in MATLAB, Octace of whatever your favorite analysis tool is. VDSP has only very limited data analysis capabilities